# Prevent close Toastr on Click

Tags: javascript, notifications, onclick, toastr

I´m trying to keep toastr open alway but it´s dissapear when I click on it, I set extendedTimeOut = 0 , however the toastr dissapear when click on it, so I need a way it never closes even when I make click on it

Comment: add some code so we'll can play with it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found a toastr option to do it

```
toastr.options.tapToDismiss = false
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w96udv4e/5/

Comment: This works ! But why doesn't it appear in chrome console auto-fill options ?

Comment: Just an addition, but I add my toastr configuration to the shared _layout page; <script> toastr.options = { "tapToDismiss": false } </script> just so people have an extra option!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
toastr.options.tapToDismiss = false;
toastr.options.disableTimeOut = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
event.stopPropogation()
```

upd [code link](https://jsfiddle.net/w96udv4e/1/)

UPD:
in sources it triggers

```
return $toastElement[options.hideMethod](...);
```

so you need to set this options to jquery function that will work on $toastElement, that makes nothing, something like an 'end' function, but you can make a noop function over all jquery elements and make hideMethod equals 'noop':

```
$.fn.noop = function(){return this;}; 
toastr.options.hideMethod = 'noop';
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w96udv4e/4/)

Comment: I have tried but it doesn´t works 

$("#toast-container").on("click",function(event){
event.stopPropagation()
});

Comment: It works but return a Javascript Error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropogation' of undefined" so the idea is that it works without errors

Comment: set toastr.options.hideMethod = 'end'; it's just like noop on click. I looked at source code and saw that on click it triggers $toastElement[options.hideMethod], so you need to set this option to such operation as noop function

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was setting `"tapToDismiss"= false` and updating the toastr script:

`toastr.options.tapToDismiss = false`

Line 273 in toastr.js:

```
if (options.onclick) {
    $toastElement.click(function () {
        options.onclick();
        if (options.tapToDismiss) hideToast(); // Line that hides toast.
    });
}
```